# Avoid having to explicitly pass in undefined prop when using a generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this type:

```
type ProviderProps<T, U> = PropsWithChildren<{
  create: (state: U) => StoreApi<T>
  state: U
}>
```

That I'm using in a component:

```
function Provider<T, U>({ create, state }: ProviderProps<T, U>) {
  // Do something with create/state here
  const values = create(state)
  return <DoSomethingWith values={values} />
}
```

The issue is that I have to pass in `undefined` as `state`, whenever I simply want to pass in a function that takes no arguments:

```
<Provider create={() => createSomeAwesomeState()} state={undefined} />
```

How can I overcome this? I want to be able to avoid passing in `state={undefined}`:

```
<Provider create={() => createSomeAwesomeState()} />
```

But when I change the signature of `ProviderProps` to

```
type ProviderProps<T, U> = PropsWithChildren<{
  create: (state: U) => StoreApi<T>
  state?: U
}>
```

Everything breaks. In particular, I can no longer pass in a `create` function because:

```
Argument of type 'U | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'U'.
  'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'U | undefined'.
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: This is a missing feature of TS, discussed in detail at [ms/TS#12400](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12400).  Right now there are just workarounds, such as using some funky conditional types for the call signature and then at least one assertion in the implementation, such as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBQ8pw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?